# Redo promise chain on error

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

When I catch an exception in a promise, is it OK to just redo the promise again or is that called an anti-pattern? I know that exceptions aren't supposed to act as flow directors but I can't seem to find any other solution to my problem.
Consider this code:

```
function a() {
    var flow = GenerateUsername().then(RegisterUserWithGeneratedUsername()).catch(DatabaseConstraintError, flow);
    return flow;
}

a();
```

What problems can this lead to? I am afraid this will be a huge memory consumer if I allocate something in the chain and it never gets resolved. Maybe it will hit the maximum call stack. How should I tackle this?

Comment: I think you have a problem with `.catch` - in 99.99% of Promise libraries, `.catch` accepts (well, uses, you can pass as many as you like they are ignored) only **one** argument

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Endlessly looping retries are usually a bad idea, but carefully retrying an operation which might intermittently fail is reasonable.

How about using something like [promise-retry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-retry)? It allows you to retry a promise chain a certain number of times. For example (from the docs):

```
promiseRetry(function (retry, number) {
    console.log('attempt number', number);

    return doSomething()
        .catch(retry);
})
.then(function (value) {
    // .. 
}, function (err) {
    // .. 
});
```

There are other alternatives, or you could roll your own.

Memory allocation: anything that's only referenced inside a callback given to `then()` will be garbage collected once it's out of scope, so unless you go out of your way to collect objects constructed on each iteration, you should be okay.